# ¿Cómo usar async await en una clase de javascript?

Tags: javascript

Básicamente, quiero hacer que, en un bucle while, dentro de una clase de javascript puedas llamar a funciones asíncronas con await para poder esperar por ellas a que se terminen de ejecutar y cuando se terminen de ejecutar volver al bucle while, para no sobresaturar la memoria del sistema.

```javascript
while(condicion) {
 if(condicion)
    await oneFunction();
 else
    await otherFunction();
}
```

Creo que no hace falta más explicación.

Comment: Debemos suponer que ese bucle está en un método de la Clase. Por otro lado, ¿a qué te refieres con que *no se sature la memoria*?

Comment: A ver, es que es complicado explicarlo por aquí, básicamente estoy haciendo un juego de cartas con interfaz gráfica en HTML, CSS y JavaScript y quiero hacer que mientras no haya terminado la partida, espere por el jugador para elegir su carta y después el CPU de su carta. Una vez haya pasado esto, que vuelva otra vez al while hasta que sea la condición de partidaTerminada true. Espero que se me haya entendido.

Comment: Todo bucle (`for` o `while`) es bloqueante. Para la que intentas tal vez sea mejor que uses programación reactiva y eventos. De esta forma no necesitas un bucle sino que simplemente escucharas eventos particulares y reaccionar a ellos. Saludos

Comment: Interesante propuesta Mauricio, lo intentaré con lo que usted dice. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.